# How to load image from one xml file into another xml file?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-imageview

I'm creating an camera app here. I've managed to click an image and display in an ImageView. I have a ImageButton on whose click takes you to another page. On the other page I want to display that image with a set of scrollable images like on Instagram. But I cant load that image on the other xml file.
Help Please.

**Code:**

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_select);

    // Image clicked...
    ImageView ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.ivPic);

    // Image button to go to next page...
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibNext);

    // Not sure if this is right.....
    Drawable iv = ivPic.getDrawable();


    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.rating.bar.EFFECTS"));
        }
    });
```

}}

In the other class I created this classes variable but I cant use iv(which holds the drawable of the image view). It only accepts integers I think. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Read the URI/Path of the image in your imagebutton and add to the extras of the intent calling the next activity and read the extras in the next activity.

Comment: well I have never used the camera to click images, tell me what do you get when the image is clicked? Do you get the URI of the clicked image? And what code do you use to set the ImgageView?